# List hidden files last

Tags: nemo, hidden-files

Most of the time when I'm using nemo, I don't want to worry about hidden files; but the times when I need to see hidden files are too numerous for me to toggle their visibility each time.

Is there an option to show all hidden files, but only after all other files? I'd want this to be a global setting, so not like the "Arrange Items" option.

Comment: Since it was developed by the Mint team, wouldn't it be better to ask there? https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-mint-84/